# Stylesheet Missing From Wordpress Theme Bones

Tags: css, wordpress

Been working on a website for the last few weeks. Had no trouble until today, when I loaded up the website it said the theme is installed but incomplete, missing stylesheet. This image displayes my problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZoQR.png

I went into the style.css on my sever and couldn't find anything wrong. Here is the first few lines of the style.css file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRB8P.jpg

Does anyone know to solve this as the website isn't for me and needs to be completed asap.

Answer (score 1):

In your style.css you are missing information WordPress needs to load the theme. The following is an example from the Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Thirteen
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/themes/twentythirteen
Author: the WordPress team
Author URI: http://wordpress.org/
Description: The 2013 theme for WordPress takes us back to the blog, featuring a full range of post formats, each displayed beautifully in their own unique way. Design details abound, starting with a vibrant color scheme and matching header images, beautiful typography and icons, and a flexible layout that looks great on any device, big or small.
Version: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: black, brown, orange, tan, white, yellow, light, one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, flexible-width, custom-header, custom-menu, editor-style, featured-images, microformats, post-formats, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, translation-ready
Text Domain: twentythirteen

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.
*/
```

You need to at least have `Theme Name`.

Answer (score 0):

On your screenshot it's look like your filename is style and not style.css

Also, i don't see the informations needed to WordPress to load a theme, see here https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*
Theme Name: Name for your theme
Theme URI: URL you want for your theme 
Author: Your name 
Author URI: Your URL
Description: Description about your theme like theme for vibe-uk.com etc.
Version: Specify version
*/
```

At-least provide above info in style.css file , that's how WordPress recognize theme its name and for thumbnail to show upload screenshot.png in theme root directory as well